# I can't make a query with multiple tables in Laravel using MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I'm using Laravel and I'm using MongoDB, but I have a problem in my `NoSQL` query that filters using `aggregate`. The SQL query works perfectly, it returns the filtering I want, but the NoSQL query does not return anything, even with the right value defined for the filtering. It simply returns nothing, no results (empty array).

- `SQL query filter (Work, just to demonstrate the structure)`

```
    $filter = $request->input('search');
    $rewarded = RewardedModel::query()
    ->select('rewardedes.id', 'hunters.name','rewards.description','rewards.value','rewardedes.done')
    ->join('hunters', 'rewardedes.hunter_id', '=', 'hunters.id')
    ->join('rewards', 'rewardedes.reward_id', '=', 'rewards.id')
    ->where('hunters.name', 'LIKE', "%$filter%")
    ->orWhere('rewards.description', 'LIKE', "%$filter%")->paginate(5);
```

- `NoSQL query filter (Doesn't work, empty query returned)`

```
    
    $filter = $request->input('search');
    $rewarded = RewardedModel::raw(function ($collection) use ($filter) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'hunters',
                    'localField' => 'hunter_id',
                    'foreignField' => '_id',
                    'as' => 'hunters'
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'rewards',
                    'localField' => 'reward_id',
                    'foreignField' => '_id',
                    'as' => 'rewards'
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    '$or' => [
                        ['hunters.name' => ['$regex' => $filter, '$options' => 'i']],
                        ['rewards.description' => ['$regex' => $filter, '$options' => 'i']]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$project' => [
                    '_id' => '$rewardedes._id',
                    'name' => '$hunters.name',
                    'description' => '$rewards.description',
                    'value' => '$rewards.value',
                    'done' => '$rewardedes.done',
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$limit' => 5
            ]
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I revised the MongoDB aggregation pipeline in your Laravel application by adding `$unwind` stages to flatten the arrays resulting from `$lookup` joins and adjusted field paths in `$match` and `$project` stages, ensuring the use of `MongoDB\BSON\Regex` for proper regex filtering. Try this

```
   $filter = $request->input('search');
    $rewarded = RewardedModel::raw(function ($collection) use ($filter) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'hunters',
                    'localField' => 'hunter_id',
                    'foreignField' => '_id',
                    'as' => 'hunter'
                ]
            ],
            ['$unwind' => '$hunter'], 
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'rewards',
                    'localField' => 'reward_id',
                    'foreignField' => '_id',
                    'as' => 'reward'
                ]
            ],
            ['$unwind' => '$reward'],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    '$or' => [
                        ['hunter.name' => ['$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($filter, 'i')]], // Use MongoDB\BSON\Regex for regex
                        ['reward.description' => ['$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($filter, 'i')]]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$project' => [
                    '_id' => 1,
                    'name' => '$hunter.name',
                    'description' => '$reward.description',
                    'value' => '$reward.value',
                    'done' => 1,
                ]
            ],
            ['$limit' => 5]
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: ```['hunter.name' => ['$regex' => new Regex($filter, 'i')]],```, but i inserted ```use MongoDB\BSON\Regex;``` in Controller anr return me *Undefined type 'MongoDB\BSON\Regex'.*

Comment: It does not still work.

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct MongoDB PHP library. If you're using the jenssegers/mongodb package for Laravel, it should provide compatibility with the native PHP MongoDB extension. If not installed, you can add it using Composer:

composer require jenssegers/mongodb